# How to find a substring inside a string via JavaScript in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

i have the following solution:

`var audience = "Nderon Hyseni John Champion Martin Tyler";`
`var _username = user.get_title(); //This variable show the user that is currently logged in`

Example:

I am logged in with a user which name is Nderon Hyseni, how can i say if _username (this username Nderon Hyseni is currently logged in) value is in `audience` variable `alert("Pass")` if not `alert(failed)`

thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i was looking for, but anyway thanks

```
var str = "NderonHyseniBurimRamusaAlenScott"; 
var test = "NderonHyseni";//username

var res = str.match(test);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;

if(res != null)    
    alert("true");

else
   alert("false");}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var audience = "Nderon Hyseni John Champion Martin Tyler";
var _username = user.get_title(); //Nderon Hyseni
if(audience.Contains(_username)){
   //found
} else {
   //not found
}
```

I haven't wrote in c# for months, but it should work.

**EDIT**
Whoooa... javascript ;D

```
var audience = "Nderon Hyseni John Champion Martin Tyler";
var _username = user.get_title(); //Nderon Hyseni
if(audience.indexOf(_username) > -1){
   //found
} else {
   //not found
}
```

This should work :)

Comment: I am note sure if this works also in JavaScript
becaus my solution is in javascript

Comment: thanks i will try this tomorrow in my office but could you explain me why is that -1 for?

Comment: but I think that this funcion .indexOf return the position of number

Comment: Sorry for such late response. Yeah indexOf does exactly what you said, and that's why there is -1. It means that _username is not present in audience. In this example it would return 0, because audience begins with string stored in _username. :)

Comment: anyway brother thanks for your time you took to watch my question.